# whmcs api data duplicated when save into database

Tags: json, api, store, whmcs

I am figuring why is there duplicated data in every data. Is there any fault in my code.

```
   // Decode response
   $jsonData = json_decode($response,true);


    //store client data in db

    $clients = $jsonData['clients']['client'];

   foreach ($clients as $client) {      
   $firstname = $companyname = $email = '';
     foreach($client as $key => $value){
        switch($key){
           case 'firstname': $firstname = $value;
            break;
           case 'companyname': $companyname = $value;
            break;
           case 'email': $email = $value;
            break;
      }
    }
         if($firstname && $companyname && email){

      $sql = "INSERT INTO members ( `firstname`, `companyname`, `email`) 
      VALUES ('$firstname', '$companyname', '$email');";
      $query = $connect->query($sql);}


      if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully"."<br>";
       } else {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error."<br>";
       }
      }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? For example, why do you call `query` twice?

Comment: i have over looked there is two query. i have removed this one: $query = $connect->query($sql);} 

but still the data is duplicated..
please help me

Comment: Then go for my first question: what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: now i have debugged and solve the issue.. Thanks